# Conditional Probability Proof

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

Suppose that X and Y are independent discrete random variables. Let h(x,y) be a
bounded two-variable function. Show that:

E [h(X,Y)|X = x] = E [h(x,Y )]

Explain why this is usually not true if X and Y are not independent!

Hint: write out both sides using the joint probability mass function

Comment: Hello, steve. What have you tried?  It would be good to see what your efforts have come up with.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how to start by using the joint probability mass function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $X$ and $Y$ are independent, the probability mass function is the product of the mass function of $X$ and the mass function of $Y$, i.e.

$$
\rho_{XY}(x,y) =\rho_X(x)\rho_Y(y)\text{ for }x\in\Omega_X,y\in\Omega_Y
$$

where $\Omega_X$ and $\Omega_Y$ are the sample spacess of $X$ and $Y$ respectively.  The unconditional expectation of $h(x,y)$ is

$$
E\left[h(X,Y)\right]=\sum_{x\in\Omega_X,y\in\Omega_Y}h(x,y)\rho_X(x)\rho_Y(y).
$$

but if X=x, the conditional expectation is given by

$$
\begin{align*}
E\left[h(X,Y)|X=x\right] & =\sum_{y\in\Omega_Y}h(x,y)\rho_Y(y)\\
& = E\left[h(x,Y)\right].
\end{align*}
$$

If X and Y are not independent, then 
$$
E\left[h(X,Y)|X=x\right]  =\sum_{y\in\Omega_Y}h(x,y)\rho_{XY}(x,y)
$$
which isn't equal to $E\left[h(x,Y)\right]$